# Вывод дней рождений

Tags: java, intellij-idea

> [Вывод дней недели Дня рождений](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1213798/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%94%d0%bd%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9/1363146#1363146)

Подскажите почему при компиляции консоль остается пустой но при этом отрабатывают все тесты? Задача реализовать метод
collectBirthdays(int year, int month, int day),
который вернёт строки, содержащие все ваши прошедшие дни рождения от нуля лет до текущей даты в требуемом формате. Дата рождения передаётся в метод тремя числами.

Есть TODO - формат требуемого вывода.

```js
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int day = 31;
    int month = 12;
    int year = 1990;

    System.out.println(collectBirthdays(year, month, day));
  }

  public static String collectBirthdays(int year, int month, int day) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(" - dd.MM.yyyy - EE", Locale.ENGLISH);
    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(year, month - 1, day, 0, 0, 0);
    Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
    int number = 0;
    while (calendar.before(today)) {
      builder.append(number).append(format.format(calendar.getTime())).append("\n");
      calendar.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);
      number++;
    }
    return builder.toString();
  }
}

//TODO реализуйте метод для построения строки в следующем виде
//0 - 31.12.1990 - Mon
//1 - 31.12.1991 - Tue
```

[image: Консоль при компиляции пуста, при этом все тесты выполнены]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: @Сергей Воробей не обращайте внимание на комментарий. Это просто проверка условия получения секретной шляпы **Helping finger**

Comment: _Подскажите почему при компиляции консоль остается пустой но при этом отрабатывают все тесты?_ Ну если в тестовых методах или самом тестируемом методе ничего не выводится в консоль, а просто выполняется проверка ожидаемых результатов, то она и останется пустой.  Тесты вызывают метод `collectBirthdays`, возвращающий некоторое значение, пригодное для тестирования, а не метод main, который выводит в консоль.

Comment: Всё заработало после переустановки JRE. Код рабочий.